Customtkinter: Close the dropdown menu when the dropdown arrow is clicked again
I have a piece CustomTkinter GUI that has several combobox dropdowns. I am having an issue with closing the popup when clicking the dropdown arrow for a second time. I have tried looking online for anybody having the same issue but I've not found much, and digging through the source code on GitHub didn't bring me any success either!
I want these dropdowns to be able to close the popups when the dropdown arrow is clicked a second time. Currently when clicking it again the popup is recreated. The way to close the popup is to click anywhere else (i.e. selecting a dropdown option, clicking the accompanying entry box, or clicking anywhere outside of the combobox).
Below is a dummy code/pseudo-code (as the toggle_dropdown method does not work) that attempts to solve my problem:
import customtkinter as ctk


class DummyApp(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.geometry('200x100')

        self.combobox = ctk.CTkComboBox(self, values=['Option A', 'Option B'])
        self.combobox.pack(side='left')
        self.combobox.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: self.toggle_dropdown(event, cbox=self.combobox))

    @staticmethod
    def toggle_dropdown(event, cbox: ctk.CTkComboBox):
        if cbox.cget('state') == 'shown':
            cbox.hide()
        else:
            cbox.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = DummyApp()
    app.mainloop()

I have tried to bind an event to my combobox such that when the dropdown arrow is clicked it will check if it is currently being displayed. If so: it closes the popup, and vice versa. This does not work because the event is being bound to the entry box rather than the dropdown arrow.
So I would like two things fixed with this code:

Bind the event to the dropdown arrow rather than the entry box (the lambda function would allow me to make the toggle_dropdown method generalisable to other comboboxes within my GUI)
Fix toggle_dropdown to correctly check the 'shown/hidden' state, and then hide/show as appropriate.

Thank you in advance for any assistance provided!

EDIT:
I could be wrong but it seems that this is a problem inherent to customtkinter. From testing this on other machines, with different versions of windows & customtkinter the problem still persists.
I have opened an issue on the GitHub, so I hope it will be looked into: https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/issues/2386
I have temporarily created an inelegant solution whereby the CTKComboBox has been replaced with a CTkOptionMenu, as the self.optionbox.bind(...) applies to the entire widget. This has allowed me to change between 'normal/disabled' states, which correctly closes the dropdown menu on a second click.
With this there was the problem after selecting an option of the widget having to be clicked twice in order to re-enable it, then select a new option. To solve this I have created a method dropdown_checker that re-enables the optionbox every 100 ms. See the below code:
import customtkinter as ctk


class DummyApp(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.geometry('200x100')

        self.optionbox = ctk.CTkOptionMenu(self, values=['Option A', 'Option B'])
        self.optionbox.pack(side='left')
        self.optionbox.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: self.toggle_dropdown(event, obox=self.optionbox))

        self.dropdown_checker()

    @staticmethod
    def toggle_dropdown(event, obox: ctk.CTkOptionMenu):
        if obox.cget('state') == 'normal':
            obox.configure(state='disabled')
        elif obox.cget('state') == 'disabled':
            obox.configure(state='normal')

    def dropdown_checker(self):
        self.optionbox.configure(state='normal')
        self.after(100, self.dropdown_checker)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = DummyApp()
    app.mainloop()


Like I said this is not a very good solution, but it is the only one I could think of whilst waiting for a reply to the GitHub issue. If anybody has any improvements/suggestions, I would love to hear them!

for the second issue CTK.Combobox only has disabled , normal and readonly options for state.

Have you tried contacting the author of customtkinter, and/or submitted an issue on github?

What platform are you on? When I run your code on my mac, clicking the arrow once opens the menu, clicking it a second time closes it.

@msamedozmen I believe that these states are for the combobox as a whole, and do not track the 'opened/closed' state of the dropdown.

@BryanOakley I am running the code on Windows 10, but another colleague has attempted to run this code on Windows 11 and has met with the same problem. I haven't submitted an issue on GitHub (I'm not very experienced with it so it did not cross my mind), thank you for the recommendation.

It worked for me on Window 10

@toyotaSupra That's strange. Which version of customtkinter are you running? I've since tested this on 5.1.0, 5.2.1 (my version), and 5.2.2. Each on a separate computer, too, and I still had this issue. I am also running this on Python 3.10 for additional context.

customtkinter 5.2.2. Python 3.12.3

In Windows platform, the dropdown menu is of system menu type which will be closed when it losts focus.  So when clicking the down arrow second time, the open menu will be closed first and open again by the bound callback.

Hello, I have made an edit to my question based on a temporary solution I have found. I have also opened an issue on the customtkinter GitHub (see my edit for a link) based on a previous comment's suggestion!
